# How do I submit a 2nd generation managed package for security review?

Tags: security-review

I am trying to get 2nd generation managed package ready for security review. It is not showing up in the devhub org. How do I submit the package. Do I zip up the source code and submit it?

I have tried locating the package in the devhub but it is showing 0 packages.

[Update]
I am listing the points from the documentation and what I have done on it.

•   Connect a Packaging Org to the Publishing Console

- As it is 2nd gen  package I do not have packaging org.

•   Create or Edit Your Provider Profile
*This is done.*

•   Create or Edit Your AppExchange Listing
*This is done.*

•   Add a Business Plan to an AppExchange Listing
*This is done.*

•   Make Your AppExchange Listing Effective

•   Select an Installation Option
We selected an option to install to admins by default.

•   Register Your Package and Choose License Settings

Is LMA required for security review ?

•   Complete the Security Review Cycle
*This is the goal.*

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish.htm)? Did you follow the steps precisely?

Comment: We are still navigating through the process. We reached a step where it showed our devhub org and showed 0 package. I am assuming if it had been 1st generation managed package it would have showed up. I saw similar question from 2019 when 2nd gen managed package was beta. So I am not sure if I need to upload all components and create package for this review or if there is another way to submit, i.e a zip of source code. I will go through the documentation again. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help?(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/isv_security_review/isv_security_review_submit)

Comment: @Vinay I am going through that document as well and assembling needed materials. Yes this one was much helpful than the text documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @sfdcfox do I have to release my app to make it appear in the packages list  so i can select that app in the App tab. I am not able to add the package and security review tab says there is nothing to review since I am not able to add the package. I am not able to add package as it is not visible because I think it is not released, and it is not released because we have not gone through security review. Going in circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You note in your question and in comments:

> I have tried locating the package in the devhub but it is showing 0 packages... [D]o I have to release my app to make it appear in the packages list so i can select that app in the App tab. I am not able to add the package and security review tab says there is nothing to review since I am not able to add the package. I am not able to add package as it is not visible because I think it is not released, and it is not released because we have not gone through security review. Going in circles

You must promote a managed release version of your application before you can submit it to Security Review. A managed beta is *not* eligible for Security Review submission. Make sure that (a) you've connected the Dev Hub that owns this package and (b) you've promoted a release to be able to select it for Security Review submission.

Note that promoting a managed release is an operation that exclusively affects the package artifact: it is *not* the same thing as posting your release on the AppExchange, which you can do after Security Review.

Other questions from your post:

> • Connect a Packaging Org to the Publishing Console

> As it is 2nd gen package I do not have packaging org.

Your Dev Hub is the "packaging org" for a 2GP package.

> • Register Your Package and Choose License Settings

> Is LMA required for security review ?

No, it is not.